# Fastapi Websocket Mutiple Chats

Tags: python, websocket, backend, fastapi, chat

I Programmed an application using flet. I also created a backend with fastapi that saves user Information and Handels the users friends. Now I Want to implement a Feature that user can chat with each other like on whats app. How do I do that? Are Websockets the right Tool for that? How Do I create multiple connections/chats etc..

I tried everything, I searched on google, Youtube, github etc. but found nothing...

Comment: you can look at [chat service](https://github.com/shashstormer/socket_service/blob/master/main.py) code implementation